# Declare a variable as dbo.Name?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, variables, sqldatatypes

I'm reading an excellent article by Paul White - [Dynamic Seeks and Hidden Implicit Conversions](https://www.sql.kiwi/2012/01/dynamic-seeks-and-hidden-implicit-conversions.html)! and he uses this code:

```
DECLARE @Like dbo.Name = N'D%'
```

I'm trying to find out more about using dbo.Name to declare a variable, not having much luck with books online. Any ideas where I can find this?

Thanks

Comment: What exactly is your question here, except asking us to google for you?

Comment: I've googled and binged but can't find out if this is a standard feature. I really would like to understand how it works.

Comment: Then why ask "Any ideas where I can find this?", instead of "can someone explain this feature?", which is actually what people have given as answers.

Comment: Poorly phrased, I agree. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Thanks SQLkiwi, I swear I was sans brain that day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dbo.Name` is a [User Defined Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175007.aspx). It's a way of introducing a synonym for another type.

The feature is not widely used (in my experience) - the standard SQL version would be `CREATE DOMAIN`, but that includes support for arbitrary constraints (see e.g. the PostgreSQL documentation for [CREATE DOMAIN](http://sepp.oetiker.ch/postgresql-8.2.4-rp/sql-createdomain.html)), whereas `CREATE TYPE` in SQL offers very little over just introducing the synonym.

Comment: Thanks, it must be a UDT on the Adventureworks database, I'll dig deeper.

Answer (score 1):

That would be a type that he has created himself. [CREATE TYPE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175007.aspx)

Perhaps something like this:

```
create type Name from nvarchar(100)
```